# Using paste when naming a list

Tags: r, list, paste

Naming a list like this works fine:

```
list("mtcars" = mtcars)
```

But when I try to use `paste`, I get an error:

```
list(paste("mtcars") = mtcars)

Error: unexpected '=' in "list(paste("mtcars") ="
```

How can I use `paste` when naming a list?

Comment: You could use `setNames(list(mtcars), paste("mtcars"))` or `names(myList) <- paste("mtcars")`.

Comment: The LHS of the `=` is actually the name of a function parameter (passed to the ellipses of `list`). You can specify that name with or without quotes, but it needs to be a valid name if you don't use quotes. A function call is not a valid name.

Comment: `setNames(list(mtcars), paste("mtcars"))` works nicely. Want to add as an answer?

Comment: @lukeA Not sure about the `paste` part, `setNames(list(mtcars), "mtcars")` should work as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can initialise the list with `myList <- list()` and then add named items with:

```
myList[[paste("mtcars")]] <- mtcars
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mget`

```
myList <- mget("mtcars")
```

It will get the values in `list` with the strings as the names.

```
str(myList)
#List of 1
# $ mtcars:'data.frame': 32 obs. of  11 variables:
#  ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#  ..$ cyl : num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
#  ..$ disp: num [1:32] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
#  ..$ hp  : num [1:32] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
#  ..$ drat: num [1:32] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
#  ..$ wt  : num [1:32] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
#  ..$ qsec: num [1:32] 16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
#  ..$ vs  : num [1:32] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
#  ..$ am  : num [1:32] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  ..$ gear: num [1:32] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
#  ..$ carb: num [1:32] 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

Comment: Tried `list(mget("mtcars") = mtcars)` but gives same error

Comment: @luciano You don't need to wrap with `list`.  Just copy/paste the code `mget("mtcars")`

Comment: Thanks - `mget` is useful to know about.  But for this question it would only give the desired result if the list names are supposed to be the same as the object names.

Comment: @Bazz Based on the example showed in the OP's post, it is the case.