# Create new column in computed data.table with name stored in another character variable

Tags: r, data.table

Right off the bat, I'm not referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391950/select-assign-to-data-table-variables-which-names-are-stored-in-a-character-ve) question. That question deals with an update by reference kind of scenario. However, if I have still missed a question, I am sorry, please close this question.

Here is what I am talking about.

```
library(data.table)
x <- setDT(copy(mtcars))
# This is possible
x[, .(mpg = mean(mpg)), keyby = cyl]

colName <- 'mpg'
# How to achieve something like this?
x[, .((colName) = mean(mpg)), keyby = cyl]
```

Is there some way to make `(colName)` work in this case? To be clear, I do not want to update `x`, but want to assign the column name directly to the newly created `data.table`.

Comment: `x[, (colName) := .(mean(mpg)), keyby = cyl]` or `x[, setNames(.(mean(mpg)), colName), keyby=cyl]`?

Comment: Sorry, should have been clear. I do not want to update `x`. But instead want to create a new `data.table`.

Comment: Thanks, do you want to add that as an answer? Although I still thought there'd be an elegant way do it than resort to `setNames`.

Comment: i think this is a dupe. Hence, you might want to close it.

Comment: @zacdav That does not work, I would have thought something like that would work. That returns an error.

Comment: @chinsoon12. Of which question would this be a dupe of? I'll be happy to close it if you can point me to the correct question.

Comment: for eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49230351/naming-a-column-in-a-list-manner-with-string-in-data-table/49230383#49230383 I rem there is a few more

Comment: @chinsoon12 Have voted to close. Thank you!